# Rewrite URL from Subdirectory to Subdomain in Rails for Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, mod-rewrite, heroku, rack-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite:

**mysite.com/blog** to **blog.mysite.com**

To be clear: I only want the user to see **mysite.com/blog** .Where the blog is actually a separately hosted wordpress site at blog.mysite.com. And mysite.com is a Rails app.

I have attempted to use [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) to achieve this and I can make it work with a 301 redirect, but not with a rewrite.

```
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Lock, Rack::Rewrite) do
  #r301   '/blog',  'http://blog.mysite.com' #works
  rewrite   '/blog',  'http://blog.mysite.com' #fails
end
```

The reason I am trying to do this in Rails and not in the webserver is because I am using Heroku for hosting and I believe it is not possible to configure this type of rewrite on Heroku.

So my question is simply, how can I achieve this rewrite?

p.s. I saw another post suggesting the use of [rack-reverse-proxy](https://github.com/jaswope/rack-reverse-proxy) but this gem seems quite old and doesn't seem to have had much development. Which makes me nervous of using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of an alternative solution, I set aside my reservations and used the [rack-reverse-proxy](https://github.com/jaswope/rack-reverse-proxy) gem. As suggested in some other posts (that SO doesn't let me link to here).

It's working fine for me (Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.12).

My code is:

```
use Rack::ReverseProxy do
   reverse_proxy /^\/blog(\/.*)$/, 'http://blog.example.com$1', opts={:preserve_host => true} #works
end
```

At the bottom of the config.ru file.

Note: In Wordpress I also needed to change the Site URL in Settings > General. I changed it to: http://example.com/blog but I kept the .htaccess file unchanged.

A final point: all my CSS and JS were referenced OK, but my local fonts weren't. I solved this by referencing the fonts in the assets directory of my rails app (as opposed to in my Wordpress theme).

Comment: do you also have a route set up? I get `no route matches`

Comment: no - I do have anything in routes relating to this. Maybe check rack-reverse-proxy is installed and working by going back to the basic example on their page: https://github.com/jaswope/rack-reverse-proxy#usage

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your blog and your website are hosted in different places.

Rewrite will only work if you want to serve up the same rails page but from a different URL.  It won't work between different hosts:
https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite#rewrite

The best solution is to be OK w/ users being redirected to a subdomain.

A couple other less ideal options:

- Use an iFrame of your blog in your rails app (this makes it hard to navigate and bookmark)
- Serve up your blog from your rails app using something like rack-reverse-proxy (this will be slow for the user and slow down the rest of your site).
- Load your blog via JavaScript after the Rails page loads (SEO won't be good and will probably be hard to navigate)

So, I recommend just using the subdomain.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond Josh. I'm keen to keep everything on the same subdomain for SEO purposes. Even though Google says it doesn't matter, [others say it does](http://moz.com/community/q/moz-s-official-stance-on-subdomain-vs-subfolder-does-it-need-updating). In the end, despite my reservations I managed to used rack-reverse-proxy successfully. I'm about to update/answer it to that effect.